# Surface Pro 3 w/ Fedora wifi issue

Tags: surface

01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88W8897 [AVASTAR] 802.11ac Wireless

Wifi will randomly disconnect as it seems the network manager will restart or crash. Internet is usable, however this interrupt makes it hard to complete larger projects. I updated to Fedora 27, but then the wifi refused to connect at all (on my stable Fedora 25 kernel it connects on startup without fail, only to break later, normally I restart to fix the connectivity issue, but this has been getting old.) Maybe there's a Marvell Linux Kernel Driver I'm missing? Or maybe something to do with akmod wl, etc.
Appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could help?

https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/howto-fix-surface-pro-3-wifi-issues/2273

It says to add this rule in the following location:

/etc/udev/rules.d/81-surfacepro3_wifi.rules

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", KERNEL=="wlp1s0", RUN+="/usr/sbin/iw dev $name set power_save off"
```